# Chrome dev tools: where does "time cached" value come from?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, service-worker

In the Application tab of the dev tools, under Cache Storage section, where does the "Time Cached" value come from?  For certain resources, the date is sensible.  For others, it's 1/1/1970 (zero Unix time).  The non-sensible ones tend to be the ones originating from my own host.  How can I change what I'm doing with these resources to make this "Time Cached" value correct?

[image]

Comment: I'd recommend using https://crbug.com/new to create an issue reporting this behavior, and include a link to a web app where it could be reproduced.

Comment: @JeffPosnick so potentially/probably it's nothing I'm actually doing wrong?

Comment: While there might be something that you could do differently to get a meaningful date to appear (I'm not sure what?), this is a public-facing feature that lots of other developers will interact with, and each of those developers shouldn't have to jump through the same hoops. Filing a bug will hopefully result in a fix for all developers.

Comment: Do you find a solution to this issue? File a bug? I still experience this issue.

Comment: @CasperAlant no, I never did find a solution :-(